# Throw a dice-expected value.

Tags: random-variables, variance, expected-value

We throw the dice three times. Let $X_i$- number of throws, in which we get number $i$. Find expected value and variance random variable $Y=\sum_{i=1}^{6} (-1)^iX_i$.
We know, that $X_i=0,1,2,3$.
$E(Y)=E(-X_1+X_2-X_3+X_4-X_5+X_6)$. But $X_i$ are not independent. And I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Can you compute the expectation of $X_i$?  For $Y$ you can use linearity of expectation, which does not need independence.

Comment: The expected value of $Y$ is just zero as all of $X_i$ should have the same value (all sides of the die have equal chances of being rolled).

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, of course. You're right.